# vb.net Post Filter

Tags: vb.net, post

I am currently building a string and require a date to be filtered.

Example :

```
sb.Append("&NextPayDate=" & app.IncomeNext.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
```

this collects a date from a form they fill in and then it gets posted out.
The problem is the area that recieves this post does not allow weekends, so the date cannot be on a weekend.

This is how i filter a telephone number and it works great

```
If app.LandPhone.Length = 10 Or app.WorkPhone.Length = 10 Then
                sb.Append("Only 11-digit phones supported;")
```

How do i filter the date so it wont accept weekend dates.

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks Novemberland, that worked great , just forget the End IF
Here is the full solution.

```
    Imports System.Globalization

Friend Overrides Function Filter() As String
Dim sb As New StringBuilder()

If (myCal.GetDayOfWeek(app.IncomeNext).equals("Saturday") or myCal.GetDayOfWeek(app.IncomeNext).equals("Sunday"))
Then
sb.Append("No weekends supported;")

            End If

            Return sb.ToString()
        End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to get/set the type of calendar you use importing:

```
Imports System.Globalization
```

Then check if `app.IncomeNext` includes that information already or use this:

```
  Dim myCal As Calendar = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar

If (myCal.GetDayOfWeek(app.IncomeNext).equals("Saturday") or myCal.GetDayOfWeek(app.IncomeNext).equals("Sunday"))
Then
sb.Append("No weekends supported;")
 End If
```

According the configuration of `app.IncomeNext` you'll probably need to insert the type of calendar.

Answer (score -1):

If app.IncomeNext.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday Or
            app.IncomeNext.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday Then